# Why printing all running threads in Java unblocks an application?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I created a GUI Application in JavaFX which communicates with a serial device (I use a [jssc connector](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector)). When I want to get data I send a communicate, then wait 1s until the *wait* function terminates. Communicate is also being sent, among other things, when I click one of the buttons (for starting a device, for identification, etc.). During development process I noticed a bug - communication hangs (but only when receiving messages, I still can send one-way communicates for ie. starting a device) when I click too many buttons too fast or I click buttons which send more than one communicate.

Communication is mainly handled by my own class **SerialPortDevice**. I create an object of a class' type and then invoke particular methods. Here's the method which waits for a message:

```
private String waitForMessage() throws SerialPortException {
    long operationStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long connectionTimeout = SerialPortCommunicationParameters.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLIS;
    String resultMessage = "";
    do {
        if (readEventOccurred) {
            System.out.println();
            resultMessage = receiveMessage();
            System.out.println("After receiving a message");
            messageReceived = true;
        }
    } while (((System.currentTimeMillis() - operationStartTime) < connectionTimeout) && (!messageReceived));
    if (!readEventOccurred) {
        resultMessage = NO_RESPONSE;
    }
    System.out.println("Time elapsed: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - operationStartTime + "ms"));
    return resultMessage;
}
```

One can notice that message is being received only when a flag **readEventOccured** is true. It's handled by my implementation of the SerialPortEventListener:

```
class SerialPortDeviceReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
  private SerialPortDevice device;

  SerialPortDeviceReader(SerialPortDevice device) {
      this.device = device;
  }

  public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
      if (event.isRXCHAR()) {
          System.out.println("Serial Event Occured!");
          device.setReadEventOccurred(true);
      }
  }
}
```

**readEventOccured** is a boolean field in the **SerialPortDevice** class which contains **waitForMessage** function. Also, **waitForMessage** is invoked by another function, **singleConversation**:

```
String singleConversation(String testMessage) {
    String resultMessage = NO_RESPONSE;
    try {
        openConnection();
        sendMessage(testMessage);
        resultMessage = waitForMessage();
        closeConnection();
    } catch (SerialPortException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return resultMessage;
    }
    System.out.println();
    readEventOccurred = false;
    messageReceived = false;

    return resultMessage;
}
```

... Which is the only function setting **readEventOccured** to false. And it is a "top level" function in a **SerialPortDevice** class which handles sending and receiving a communicates to and from a device.
So communication looks like this:
Button click -> Button handler invocation -> device.singleCommunication(buttons_specific_communicate) -> some methods run and then it comes to the waitForMessage -> *method waits 1s for the event* -> event occurs (everytime - I get the "Serial Event Occured" communicate) -> readEventOccured is being set to true -> if there is some time left (there is always **some** time left, everything lasts a miliseconds), message is being received in the waitForMessage method.

There is no problem if I click buttons with a short (in a human sense, 2-3s for example) delay or I don't click these which do send more than one communicate inside their handlers. In different situations weird things happen. I still get the message "Serial Event Occured" (so I suppose **readEventOccured** is also being set to true) but waitForMessage function does not execute

```
if(readEventOccured)
```

statement's code. Also, I have to run an application again to be able to communicate with a device (I mean *receiving data*, sending works perfectly).

What solved my problem was adding "volatile" modifier to the readEventOccured flag (makes sense by the way, things go fast sometimes). But it didn't please me. I wanted to make a code to run correctly without "volatile". My coworker came up with an idea something goes wrong with threads that are being created when I click buttons and invoke communication - maybe something blocks other thing somewhere? First thing I did was to print all the currently runnig threads and... Man, it solved a problem. App was not hanging anymore. Really, I performed "hanging" scenarios 10-20 times with and without

```
      Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
      System.out.println(threadSet);
```

at the beginning of the waitForMessage method and result were unambigous - it somehow removed my problem.
I'm almost certainly sure getting and printing threads is not a solution itself. It's something that is being done by the way but I can't find out what is this. Any useful information? Maybe better understanding Threads in Java would help me? Or it is something else?

Cheers

Comment: A better understanding of threads is definitely recommended. Java multithreading is one of those things that are almost impossible to learn on a trial-and-error basis.

Comment: Yeah, I think that some good quality theory will help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing is the [textbook example of what happens when there are no visibility guarantees](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile). If we distil your code into its essential bits, we get something like this:

```
boolean flag = false;

void consume() {
    while (true) {
       if (flag) {
          //we received flag, hooray
       }
    }
}

void produce() {
    flag = true;
}
```

Now, if `produce()` and `consume()` run in different threads, there is absolutely no guarantee that `consume()` will EVER see `flag` set to true. `volatile` creates a memory barrier, meaning that all reads/writes of those variable will be fully ordered.

What you also have in the code though, is lots of `System.out.println()` lines. These complicate the picture, as they themselves are synchronized, and thus create [happens-before relationships](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) between different parts of the code. Unfortunately they don't create the correct sequence, but poke in a few more and you can **accidentally** get it right. The key word here is "accidentally", you shouldn't rely on this behaviour at all.

So marking `readEventOccurred` as `volatile` sort of fixes the problem but going a bit further we can see that your `waitForMessage()` spin-waits, which is rarely a good idea. I would take a look at the [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) class for example, designed for similar scenarios. (An even better candidate is its close friend, [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> What solved my problem was adding "volatile" modifier to the readEventOccured flag (makes sense by the way, things go fast sometimes). But it didn't please me. I wanted to make a code to run correctly without "volatile".

The fact that adding volatile fixes the problem indicates you've run into the lack of guarantees by the Java Memory Model when multiple threads are involved. Simply put there is no guarantee of when a change on one thread is visible on other threads except for specific situations.

The probably reason why printing 'fixes' the problem is the fact that it:

1. Changes the timing of the program, might mean the situation in which it fails no longer exists.
2. Temporarily suspends the threads to read out their current state, maybe the JVM also uses that as an opportunity to synchronize memory.

Multithreaded communication is hard, so I recommend you take a look at the classes available in [java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), which have guarantees that you might be able to use to solve your problem more elegantly.

Comment: Also `System.out.println()`is synchronized (even though the documentation doesn't say so), so it creates a happens-before relationship between subsequent invocations.

Comment: @biziclop Was not aware of that, but makes sense when you think about it

Comment: @Kiskae Thanks, I'll check this.